# Как взять два объекта из списка, в котором объекты в одной строке в dict

Tags: python, json, telebot

данный код рабочий, после получения данных от сервера, json возвращает вот такой list в одну строку. Бот выводит только артикул loftvase1white, а другой не могу вывести. Пробовал сделать вот так article1 =i[0]['supplierArticle']; article2 =i[1]['supplierArticle'] но выдает ошибку

вот из этого листа: [{'incomeId': 9059690, 'supplierArticle': 'drinkerwhitedeer01'}, {'incomeId': 9059690,'supplierArticle': 'loftvase1white'}]

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome (message):
    #API ключ х64
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи дату и время: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_incomes)

def get_incomes(message):
    URL_INCOMES = 'https://suppliers-stats.wildberries.ru/api/v1/supplier/incomes'
    API_KEY = 'ключ'
    Date = message.text
    params = {
        'key': API_KEY,
        'dateFrom': Date
    }
    res = requests.get(URL_INCOMES, params=params).json()
    #print(res)
    for i in res:
        article =i['supplierArticle']
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Артикул товара: {article}')
```

Comment: Похоже, у Вас `bot.send_message` вне цикла for, поэтому только один и выводит.

Comment: @Alex Titov
Благодарю Вас, помогло! Невнимательность...